# Can I access the total number of groups in a data.table in j?

Tags: r, data.table

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a very convenient group index called `.GRP` that can be accessed in `j` like so:

```r
# Load data table package
library(data.table)

# Create dummy data
dt <- data.table(alpha = 1:10)

# Function that takes the group number
# as an argument
foo <- function(a){
  paste0("Group #: ", a)
}

# Group by "alpha" and pass group # to "foo"
dt[, foo(.GRP), by = alpha]
#>     alpha          V1
#>  1:     1  Group #: 1
#>  2:     2  Group #: 2
#>  3:     3  Group #: 3
#>  4:     4  Group #: 4
#>  5:     5  Group #: 5
#>  6:     6  Group #: 6
#>  7:     7  Group #: 7
#>  8:     8  Group #: 8
#>  9:     9  Group #: 9
#> 10:    10 Group #: 10
```

Above, the function `foo` takes the group number (`.GRP`) and pastes it into a string. This is a toy example, but it can be really useful.

**My question**: Is there a similar variable for the *total* number of groups?

For the example above, I could calculate the total number of groups with `uniqueN`, like below, but is there already a special variable in place that does this?

```r
# Access total number of groups
dt[, foo(paste0(.GRP, "/", uniqueN(dt$alpha))), by = alpha]
#>     alpha             V1
#>  1:     1  Group #: 1/10
#>  2:     2  Group #: 2/10
#>  3:     3  Group #: 3/10
#>  4:     4  Group #: 4/10
#>  5:     5  Group #: 5/10
#>  6:     6  Group #: 6/10
#>  7:     7  Group #: 7/10
#>  8:     8  Group #: 8/10
#>  9:     9  Group #: 9/10
#> 10:    10 Group #: 10/10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sounds like a worthy feature-request.

Comment: Wouldn't `length(unique(dt$alpha))` do the exact same thing?

Comment: @Sam From `help(uniqueN)` : " `uniqueN` is equivalent to `length(unique(x))` when `x` is an atomic vector … " So, yes.

Comment: @markus ah I was not familiar with that. Good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `uniqueN` on the table, which is necessary if grouping by multiple columns:

```
> ng = uniqueN(dt, by="alpha")
> dt[, cat(sprintf("Running group % 10s/%s\n", .GRP, ng)), by=alpha]
Running group          1/10
Running group          2/10
Running group          3/10
Running group          4/10
Running group          5/10
Running group          6/10
Running group          7/10
Running group          8/10
Running group          9/10
Running group         10/10
```

This info might eventually be cached/stored with the object [per a FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2879).

Also a [request for `.NGRP`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1206#issuecomment-297105082) which I believe would solve OP's problem.

Comment: The request for `.NGRP` answers my question of whether a special variable already exists. Thanks, I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `by=alpha` that is doing the work. Just count the number of rows in the result of a trivial calculation:

```
nrow(dt[ , 1, by=alpha])
[1] 10
```

If you need ti for annotation purposes:

```
dt[ , paste(.GRP, "/", nrow(dt[ , 1, by=alpha]) ), by=alpha]
    alpha      V1
 1:     1  1 / 10
 2:     2  2 / 10
 3:     3  3 / 10
 4:     4  4 / 10
 5:     5  5 / 10
 6:     6  6 / 10
 7:     7  7 / 10
 8:     8  8 / 10
 9:     9  9 / 10
10:    10 10 / 10
```

Comment: That's for the reply. What's the benefit of `nrow(dt[ , 1, by=alpha])` over `uniqueN(dt$alpha)`? Performance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that staying in the data.table framework would give better performance, not that it matters in this instance. Using `$` results in coercion of the data.table to a data.frame process.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise about the coercion. So, also sticking in the data.table framework, `dt[, uniqueN(alpha)]` would be fast?

Comment: @Lyngbakr `uniqueN(dt[["alpha"]])` *should* be the fastest, calling `DT[...` is known to have some overhead.